# Select query using NEAR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple employee table with the columns below:

```
LastName, FirstName, FullName, Company, City, State
```

Users wants to be able to search with a single select query that will allow them to type a phrase such as "Bob Smith Company1" or "Bob Smith San Francisco CA" or the dream "Robert Smith San Francisco" and somehow get a list of employees that match that criteria.

Is this possible to do? It seems like the SQL Server feature for NEAR might help or is there another way to do this?

One restriction I have is that I need to take the input from the user in a single value, IE: they don't want to type firstname, lastname, company, state, etc. in separate columns.

Any ideas are appreciated. We are using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to allow your users to enter a single phrase which in turn would then search against the first name, last name, and address columns?

Comment: Correct ! not exact address but company / city / state

Comment: why not use the like keyword???

Comment: Does this answer your questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637757/sql-query-search-across-multiple-fields

Comment: No - in the answer they have the text parsed out in individual phrases... also the answer seems to be basic AND/OR logic... there has to be a better way.

Comment: In that case you can use `Full-Text Search` functionality of `SQL Server`. Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @iVad thank you! This is getting my closer... now how do I sort the results for relevance? Every time I run a freetext search the order changes even if the query is the same